# Function pointer with GCC, assigning an address

Tags: c, gcc, function-pointers

I have encountered something I thoroughly don't understand.
There is a function prototype:

```
typedef void ( * TMain ) ( void );
```

and a function variable:

```
TMain myFunc = MyFunc;
...
myFunc ();
```

This works fine, of course. Why should it not.

From the MAP-file I know that "MyFunc" is at location 0x20100.
And now the funny thing. After the assignment "myFunc = MyFunc;" the variable "myFunc" *does not* contain the value 0x20100 but rather 0x20101!

My problem is, that I need to call a function of which I know the address from a table. So I thought I could do it like that

```
myFunc = ( TMain ) myTable [ 5 ];    // that would be 0x20100
myFunc ();                           // which produces a proper crash
```

However If I do

```
myFunc = ( TMain ) ( ( Int8 * ) myTable [ 5 ] + 1 );  
myFunc ();
```

then it works.

What happens here? Do I always have to add an offset of 1 or is this more or less accidental? 
Or is there a better (and working) way to accomplish the task?

Thanks a lot for any hint.
Walter

Comment: Not sure, but this might be architecture-dependent. So might want to say which is the target architecture.

Comment: Is the `myTable` array of type `TMain[]`? I presume it is not since you are casting it.

Comment: Some questions for you: What platform are you using (ARM, x86...)? Have you ever checked the actual address of the function with a debugger? Can you see how the compiler generates the indirect call "myFunc()" ?

Comment: why do you store the addresses rather the functions? instead of declaring `int myTable[N]` you could do `TMain myTable[N]` and later you don't need a cast: `myfunc = myTable[5]`, or you call directly `mytable[5]()` even if you do cast the functions to fill the array it will work properly.

Comment: Or-ing in the 1 might be more appropriate for setting Thumb mode here.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is you're on an ARM target and you've built your program in Thumb mode? (Thumb is default on ARM Ubuntu or Linaro.)

The bottom bit of a function's address tell the CPU in which instruction set it should interpret the function. 0 is ARM mode. 1 is Thumb mode. Thus all Thumb-mode function pointers will be odd.

Other architectures use this idiom also, in one way or another. Usually it safe to just zero the bottom two bits of an address (making it 4-byte aligned) and assume that that is the true location of the function.

Answer (score 3):

Several CPU architectures reserve the first bytes of a function for specific purposes.  VAXen have a save register mask there.  CDC Cyber puts the return address there.  Some use some bits of the "address" to indicate address indirection (offhand I can't remember which ones, but they are from the 1970s).

Unless you truly know what you are doing, you should not write code which does that kind of pointer arithmetic.  Assign the variable the function name and be done with it:  that is guaranteed to work on every `C` implementation.